# Way to Show that a limit does not exist

Tags: calculus

how can I show that the limit of the function:
$\displaystyle f(x)=2x\sin(1/x)-\cos(1/x)$ does not exist as $xto0$?

Comment: Take two sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $f(x_n) \to a$ and $f(y_n) \to b$ with $a\neq b$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am sorry, I do not understand what you mean. can you please try to explain it in limits or aritmetica?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The $\cos$ and $\sin$  functions are $2\pi$ periodic, and more importantly as $x\to0^\pm$ we have $1/x\to\pm\infty$.

Comment: To the downvoter: please just tell me what's wrong with this answer so that I'll fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As $\left|\sin\frac1x\right|\le1,\lim_{x\to0}2x\cdot\sin\dfrac1x=0$

But $\lim_{x\to0^{\pm}}\dfrac1x=\pm\infty,\implies \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac1x$ is undefined

So, will be $\lim_{x\to0}\cos\dfrac1x$

Comment: it is enough to show that one part of the function doesn't have limit?

Comment: @user3708158, provided the other part converges to a finite number